# Storyboard doesn't display assets after migrating to Asset Catalog

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, asset-catalog

After migrating image resources to an Asset Catalog the app builds and runs correctly but the assets don't show up in Xcode's storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case this occurred because I used the full asset name including file extension (i.e. '.png') in Storyboard.

[image]

However, the name for the asset needs to match the name of the Image Set in the Asset Catalog:

[image]

So by removing '.png' from the image name in Storyboard it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem that storyboard just not display the images I set in Asset.

But my case is a little bit different. And the answer is pretty simple.

I only drag one image to the image set and accidently put it to "3x" where storyboard would load "1x" from image set.

[image]

Hope this would help someone else and save their time. Don't make the silly mistake as I did.