# Assets in asset catalog inaccessible to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode-storyboard, asset-catalog

I am migrating a project to iOS 9, and I want to place all my images into an asset catalog to take advantage of app thinning.

So far I have created an asset catalog in my project with all the images in the project, and I have removed the individual image files from the project.

The app runs, and on the simulator the images appear, but when I look at the storyboard, there is now a blue "?" box where each of the images should be.

How can I get the storyboard to recognize the assets in the asset catalog?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19006002/3134130

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks!

Comment: welcome your problem solved?

Comment: Yep just removed the .png extensions from the image names in the storyboard and everything's working.